# How to make a change in the VoiceMail Asterisk 11

Tags: asterisk

New to asterisk, and have to support an old installation. If I need to change the voicemail options, is the only way to change the  ./usr/local/src/asterisk/apps/app_voicemail.c  file?

After changing it, how would I go about it?

This is what I gathered from my research:

You need to run:

./configure

make menuconfig (and adjust the settings to match your current system)

make

make install

all as root

I am also horrible at Linux, so can someone enlighten me on the process to change VoiceMail config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app_voicemail have no settings for changing options.

You can rewrite it using AGI or can rewrite source code. Both will be offtopic here(not one page).

Here is all options you can control without coding:

```
pro-sip*CLI> core show application VoiceMail

  -= Info about application 'VoiceMail' =- 

[Synopsis]
Leave a Voicemail message. 

[Description]
This application allows the calling party to leave a message for the specified
list of mailboxes. When multiple mailboxes are specified, the greeting will be
taken from the first mailbox specified. Dialplan execution will stop if the
specified mailbox does not exist.
The Voicemail application will exit if any of the following DTMF digits are
received:
    0 - Jump to the 'o' extension in the current dialplan context.
    * - Jump to the 'a' extension in the current dialplan context.
This application will set the following channel variable upon completion:
${VMSTATUS}: This indicates the status of the execution of the VoiceMail
application.
    SUCCESS
    USEREXIT
    FAILED

[Syntax]
VoiceMail(mailbox[@context][&mailbox[@context][&...]][,options])

[Arguments]
options
    b: Play the 'busy' greeting to the calling party.

    d([c]): Accept digits for a new extension in context <c>, if played during
    the greeting. Context defaults to the current context.

    g(#): Use the specified amount of gain when recording the voicemail
    message. The units are whole-number decibels (dB). Only works on supported
    technologies, which is DAHDI only.

    s: Skip the playback of instructions for leaving a message to the calling
    party.

    u: Play the 'unavailable' greeting.

    U: Mark message as 'URGENT'.

    P: Mark message as 'PRIORITY'.
```